# Can you help me decide on this JavaScript design problem?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have a code as follow in making an object:

```
var myObject = {
    Init: function() {
        // config anything here to initiate this object.
    };
}
```

Where myObject.Init() performs like a constructor of a class. I use this Init() to generalize the object to be initiated in a following factory pattern:

```
window[myObjectName].Init();
```

myObjectName is whatever name of the object to create.

Then again I have a 2nd choice to create an object, which is much more easier for me to actually turn the Init() into a some sort of a constructor like the code below:

```
var myObject = function() {
    // config anything here to initiate this object.
}
```

With the code above, I can simply create an object like the following:

```
window[myObjectName]();
```

and practically reduces myObject code on having Init() attached to it (and every other object I would do in the factory).

However the 2nd choice comes with a disadvantage I discovered, where I can't use `this` inside the object, that I actually have to explicitly use `myObject` to call things inside. For example:

```
var myObject = function() {
    myObject.doSomething(); // instead of this.doSomething();
}
```

Which concerns me a little on variable/object reference (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Any help on these choices' advantages and disadvantages? which do you prefer on both of these choices or can you suggest a better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a constructor function? Both approaches that you suggested requires the object to be created and stored before it can be initialised. You can do like this:

```
function MyObject() {
  this.x = 1;
  this.y = 2;
}
```

You use the `new` keyword to create the objects:

```
window[myObjectName] = new MyObject();
```

Another advantage with this is that you can use the prototype of the function to add methods to the objects that are created:

```
MyObject.prototype = {

  doSomething: function() {
    // do something
  }

  doMore: function() {
    // do more
  }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways to create class structures in js. My personal preference, though is for something like your second example.

```
var MyClass = function() {
    // define local variables
    var x = 0;
    function doSomething()
    {
       return ++x;
    }
    function doSomethingTwice()
    { 
        doSomething(); 
        doSomething(); 
    }

    // basically an export section where variables are assigned "public names"
    this.doSomething = doSomething;
    this.doSomethingTwice = doSomethingTwice;
    // careful though, this next line WON'T WORK!
    this.x = x; // because this is an assignment by value, this.x will be 0 
                // no matter how many times you `doSomething`
};
var inst = new MyClass(); // the `new` keyword is imperative here
                          // otherwise `this` won't work right.
```

Comment: Thanks cwallenpoole, and your last code comment answered why **this** in my code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Arly, in my uderstanding, you should definitely be able to use `this.doSomething()`. What is the error you're getting at that line of code?

Comment: It's not working because he or she is not using `new` to call the function as a constructor.

Comment: Sorry nnnnnn but I'm not sure you've read my response properly. I am saying that the code should not result in an error: var myObject = function() {
    this.doSomething();
}

Comment: Well it's hard to tell from the original post because the code keeps swapping back and forth from `myObject` to `myObjectName`, but it seems to me that Arly's intention is to create objects using a function that makes use of `this` to refer to the new object and that won't work unless the function is called using `new`. Otherwise `this` will refer to _something_, just (probably) not something useful at that point.

Comment: nnnnnn exactly got my point and the solution. Sorry to confuse you pedrodg, I wasn't expecting to use **new**. If I do, yes it'll work with what you've answered. I'm trying to make the object stays static yet **this** still could refer to its own, but yeah it won't work unless I'm using **new**.

Comment: Fair enough. I was merely pointing out that you can use this. in the code as Guffa has pointed out in the answer marked correct. But yes, when instantiating an instance of the struct you would have to use new.

Answer (score 0):

The second way is actually the preferred one.
`this` in JavaScript does not always refer to the current object. You usually keep a reference around to your object so that you don't have to rely on `this`.

Even when you write your code with the .Init function I as a caller can override your this by doing a

```
window[myObjectName].Init.call(mynewthis);
```

In JavaScript the caller decides on what `this` will refer to.